# MongoDB Projection vs For Loops

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, projection

I want to access some data from my mongo database wrt some logic and to return the values of certain keys.
For example, let the user data be something like this.

```
[
  {
   "_id": 1,
   "name":"abc",
   "age":"25",
   "sport":"football"
  },
  {
   "_id": 2,
   "name":"def",
   "age":"18",
   "sport":"boxing"
  },
  {
   "_id": 3,
   "name":"ghi",
   "age":"22",
   "sport":"cricket"
  },
 ]
```

Now I want to return only the name and age values.

First approach,

```
const users = await this.User.find({});
let userList = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
        {
            let user = users[i];

            let t =
            {
                name : user.name,
                age: user.age
            }

            userList.push(t);
        }   

return userList;
```

Second approach,

```
    const users = await this.User.find({}, {"name":1, "age":1, _id:0, 
    "sport":0});

    return users;
```

So, if we ignore the number of lines in code, which implementation is better, and Why?

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is better because you save time and memory. when you use for loop it's take more time. also when you save users in `userList` you copy your data. so its take more time and memory.